# How to solve the CURL HTTP code 400 request in php?

Tags: php, curl

I am using the below function in php when i am sending the remarks in number like 4312 then its working fine but when i change the remarks variable value to string like "your password is change and OYP is 4312" then its give me the bad request 400 error

```
function sms_gateway($user_mobile,$remarks,$RequestNo)
{


    $curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://eample.com/?MobileNo='.$user_mobile.'&SMSText='.$remarks.'&FileReferenceNo='.$RequestNo,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
]);
// Send the request & save response to $resp

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
print_r($info);
die();

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
return($resp);

}
```

Comment: please user " quote for remarks like this  `CURLOPT_URL => 'http://eample.com/?MobileNo='.$user_mobile.'&SMSText="'.$remarks.'"&FileReferenceNo='.$RequestNo,`

Comment: Array ( [url] => http://example.com/?MobileNo=9999999999&SMSText="OTP for changing Password on Portal is 5856"&FileReferenceNo=3792028 [content_type] => text/html; charset=us-ascii [http_code] => 400 [header_size] => 179 [request_size] => 247

Comment: its working or not?

Comment: NO still give 400 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try with this remarks pass to post array in CURL

```
function sms_gateway($user_mobile,$remarks,$RequestNo)
    {


   $curl = curl_init();
    $post_data=array();
    $remarks = "your password is change and OYP is 4312";
    $str = str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", strip_tags($remarks));
    $MessageText = str_replace(' ','%20',$str);     
    $cronurl = 'http://eample.com/?';
    $url = $cronurl.'MobileNo='.$user_mobile.'&SMSText='.$MessageText.'&FileReferenceNo='.$RequestNo,


// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'

]);
// Send the request & save response to $resp

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
print_r($info);
die();

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
return($resp);

    }
```

Comment: file is there but that file needs three parameters but in my request only two are sending remarks are not sending as per this way CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data

Comment: How can i change that file that is third party file which i need to send paramerters

Comment: @sumitkundan  recently just update my answer . just try this and let me know it worked or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197336/discussion-between-kaushal-shah-and-sumit-kundan).